# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.2.0.Final - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, spring-transactions

**Hi,** 
I got this error and i can`t figure why? all of the defintions in there place and still i have this error while i trying to insert data to my DB.

- the "tx:annotation-driven" is in the appconfig-data.xml
- I call the add function from "UserController"

What could be the reason it does not work?

**Error log:**

```
יול 08, 2016 1:06:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [searcher] in context with path [/Searcher] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:454)
    at com.searcher.dao.EcommerceImp.add(EcommerceImp.java:28)
    at com.searcher.controller.UserController.registration(UserController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at
```

**Classes**

** UserController.java"

```
package com.searcher.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.searcher.dao.RoleDAO;
import com.searcher.entity.RoleEntity;
import com.searcher.entity.UserEntity;
import com.searcher.service.SecurityService;
import com.searcher.service.UserService;
import com.searcher.validator.UserValidator;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @Autowired
    RoleDAO roleDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserEntity());

        try {
            // Creatinw Role Entity
            RoleEntity roleUser = new RoleEntity();
            RoleEntity roleAdmin = new RoleEntity();

            roleUser.setName("ROLE_USER");
            roleAdmin.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");

            roleDAO.add(roleUser);
            roleDAO.add(roleAdmin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw e;
        }


        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserEntity userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.add(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getName(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**UserEntity.java**

```
package com.searcher.entity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="User_Id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long Id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name="Password")
    private String Password;

    @Column(name="Password_Confirm")
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @Column(name="Phone")
    private String Phone;

    @Column(name="Email")
    private String Email;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=RoleEntity.class)
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    public Set<RoleEntity> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<RoleEntity> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }
    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Id = " + Id + ", Name = " + Name + ", Password = " + Password + ", Phone = " + Phone + ", Email = " + Email;
    }
}
```

**RoleEntity**

```
package com.searcher.entity;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class RoleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String Name;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=UserEntity.class)
    private Set<UserEntity> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    public Set<UserEntity> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<UserEntity> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

**UserDAOImp**

```
package com.searcher.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.searcher.entity.UserEntity;

@Repository
public class UserImp implements UserDAO{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(UserEntity user) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(user);
        logger.info("UserEntity saved successfully, UserEntity Details="+user);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(UserEntity user) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
        logger.info("UserEntity updated successfully, UserEntity Details="+user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        UserEntity userToDelete = getUserById(id);
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(userToDelete);
        logger.info("UserEntity deleted successfully, UserEntity Details="+userToDelete);
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity getUserById(int id) {
        UserEntity userReturn = (UserEntity)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(UserEntity.class, id);

        logger.info("UserEntity founded successfully, UserEntity Details="+userReturn);

        return userReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity getUserByName(String name) {
        try{
            UserEntity userReturn = 
                    (UserEntity)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user where Name ='" + name + "'");

            if (userReturn != null){
                logger.info("UserEntity founded successfully, UserEntity Details="+userReturn);
            }
            else{
                logger.info("UserEntity Not found with Name= "+userReturn);
            }

            return userReturn;
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> getAllUser() {
        List<UserEntity> userList = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user").list();
        logger.info("List<UserEntity> upload successfully, List<UserEntity> Details="+userList.toString());
        return userList;
    }

}
```

**RoleDAOIMP**

```
package com.searcher.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.searcher.entity.RoleEntity;

@Repository
public class RoleImp implements RoleDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(RoleEntity role) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(role);
        logger.info("RoleEntity saved successfully, RoleEntity Details="+role);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(RoleEntity role) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(role);
        logger.info("RoleEntity updated successfully, RoleEntity Details="+role);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        RoleEntity roleToDelete = getRoleById(id);
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(roleToDelete);
        logger.info("RoleEntity deleted successfully, RoleEntity Details="+roleToDelete);
    }

    @Override
    public RoleEntity getRoleById(int id) {
        RoleEntity roleReturn = (RoleEntity)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(RoleEntity.class, id);

        logger.info("RoleEntity founded successfully, RoleEntity Details="+roleReturn);

        return roleReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public RoleEntity getRoleByName(String name) {
        RoleEntity roleReturn = 
                (RoleEntity)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNamedQuery("from role where Name =" + name);

        logger.info("RoleEntity founded successfully, RoleEntity Details="+roleReturn);

        return roleReturn;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public List<RoleEntity> getAllRole() {
        List<RoleEntity> roleList = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from role").list();
        logger.info("List<RoleEntity> upload successfully, List<RoleEntity> Details="+roleList.toString());
        return roleList;
    }

}
```

**UserServiceImp**

```
package com.searcher.service;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.searcher.dao.RoleDAO;
import com.searcher.dao.UserDAO;
import com.searcher.entity.UserEntity;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

    //@Autowired(required=true)
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public RoleDAO getRoleDAO() {
        return roleDAO;
    }

    public void setRoleDAO(RoleDAO roleDAO) {
        this.roleDAO = roleDAO;
    }

    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getbCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    public void setbCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(UserEntity user) {
        try {
            user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleDAO.getAllRole()));
            this.userDAO.add(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void edit(UserEntity user) {
        this.userDAO.edit(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        this.userDAO.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserEntity getUserById(int id) {
        return this.userDAO.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserEntity getUserByName(String name) {
        return this.userDAO.getUserByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<UserEntity> getAllUser() {
        return this.userDAO.getAllUser();
    }
}
```

**RoleServiceImpl**

```
package com.searcher.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.searcher.dao.RoleDAO;
import com.searcher.entity.RoleEntity;


public class RoleServiceImp implements RoleService {

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;


    public RoleDAO getRoleDAO() {
        return roleDAO;
    }

    public void setRoleDAO(RoleDAO roleDAO) {
        this.roleDAO = roleDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(RoleEntity role) {

        this.roleDAO.add(role);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void edit(RoleEntity role) {
        this.roleDAO.edit(role);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        this.roleDAO.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public RoleEntity getRoleById(int id) {
        return this.roleDAO.getRoleById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public RoleEntity getRoleByName(String name) {
        return this.roleDAO.getRoleByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<RoleEntity> getAllRole() {
        return (List<RoleEntity>)this.roleDAO.getAllRole();
    }
}
```

**This is the folowing configuration files:**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Searcher</display-name>

    <!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components that makeup this application -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>searcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>searcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    -->

    <!--  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>searcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>-->


</web-app>
```

**appconfig-root.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="appconfig-mvc.xml"/>

    <import resource="appconfig-data.xml"/>

    <import resource="appconfig-security.xml"/>

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Component classes to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.searcher.*"/>

    <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>-->

</beans>
```

**appconfig-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.searcher.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
          class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**appconfig-data.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <!-- DataSource -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SearcherDB" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.RoleEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.UserEntity</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <!-- <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>  -->
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>



    <!-- User -->
    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.UserImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.searcher.service.UserServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Role -->
    <beans:bean id="roleDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.RoleImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans>
```

**appconfig-mvc.xml**

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 


</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using non transactional daos in your `UserController.registration` method:

```
roleDAO.add(roleUser);
roleDAO.add(roleAdmin);
```

Use `RoleServiceImpl` instead.

Comment: Wow, I'm on it full time! But most attempts to fix it, I did not see, thank you very much